# How do I get response of Javascript using JavascriptExecutor in Java selenium or how to extract <script> tag text?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Here I want to get extract the value from the  tag. But through the selenium, I am not able to find script tag and fetch data for the same.

But through Javascript, I am able to access that script tag and fetch the value. The script is like below,

```
<script class="payload-script"> Text </script>
```

> $(".payload-script").text();

but now I want to run this script through JavascriptExecutor and get value to java variable so I can do further processing.

Comment: What's the code you have tried and what was the output of that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In selenium - JavaScriptExecutor is an interface that provides a mechanism to execute Javascript through selenium driver.**

**Please use the below code:**

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String textValue = (String) jse.executeScript("return document.getElementsByClassName('payload-script')[0].text");
System.out.println(textValue);
```

**Another way:**

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.className("payload-script"));
String textValue2 = (String) jse.executeScript("return arguments[0].text", el);
System.out.println(textValue2);
```